# How to make someone admin after deploying?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I haven't deployed my app yet and I am actually far from it. I am actually implementing the admin interface in my app now. But here is a question that I'd like to ask before I implement it.

I am going to add an admin column, which will be a `boolean` with `default value: false` to the Users table. Admin is obviously not going to be included in `attr_accessible`. In development, I can change the value of admin by issuing: `user.toggle!(:admin)` in the console.

How do I that once I have deployed my app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood you correctly

If you want role based authorization There are many gems available for adding roles for users

https://github.com/be9/acl9

https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/Role-Based-Authorization

[Rails 3: Devise add roles checkboxes to registration form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4622635/rails-3-devise-add-roles-checkboxes-to-registration-form)

> How to make someone admin after deploying?

Using database seed you can create/set admin

For more info: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/command_line.html#rake

### Update:

```
admin_user = User.create!(
      :login => 'admin_username',
      :email => 'admin@app.com',
      :password => 'Secret',
      :password_confirmation => 'Secret',
      :is_admin => true 
    )
 #change the column names to yours
```

Comment: What I mean is lets I deploy my app. I register for my app through the Sign up functionality and I am the first user. But now I am  a normal user. Now how can i make myself admin?

Comment: I think you have to do it manually in DB or via Rails Console

Comment: But how after deploying? Or do I create my profile in the db before deploying. Make myself admin and then deploy with the db?

Comment: No.. You can use seeds.rb file to create a user.. after deploying and migrating you just need to run rake db:seed command.. That will create you a admin user

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Active Admin](https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin) gem to build Admin Support for your application. It is very easy to integrate also and give lots of admin functionality.

see tutorial [here](http://activeadmin.info/documentation.html)